# Detail of IIS Log entry

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, user-agent, iis-logs

I see entires in my IIS logs with the below user agent. What does this mean?

> Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+en-US;+rv:1.9.0.3)+Gecko/2008092417+Firefox/3.0.3+[UsableNet+Lift+Mobile]

Specifically, the **UsableNet+Lift+Mobile** part?

Comment: Firefox is open source, so it is likely to be a custom build.

Comment: UsableNet's LIFT software is a core semantic analysis technology that is packaged in several forms by UsableNet depending on developer or tester needs.  http://jimthatcher.com/lifteval.htm